# Mapping from spinor to tetrad

Tags: differential-geometry, group-theory, group-representations, spinors, dirac-matrices

I am reading the journel by Patrick l. Nash: mapping from tetrad to Dirac spinor.  While reading this ,I came across  the term concrete real 4*4 irreducible representation of SO(3,3).
I know SO(3) is a special orthogonal group of rotations in R^3 and it is a 3*3 orthogonal matrix where determinant is +1.
       Now I am having a problem of understanding the extra 3 in SO(3,3) and  How can real 4*4 irreducible representation be related with Dirac gamma matrix?
Would be better if provided by matrix example.